# RestSharp giving me BadRequest when calling it from Repository

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, restsharp

I'm having this problem when trying to make a RestRequest from the repository, and the exact same request made from the API Controller goes OK.

```
   public IRestResponse SendOrderToBringg(string json)
    {
        RestClient client = new RestClient(_configuration.GetValue<string>("EndPoint:EnvioPedidos"));

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

        request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = client.Post(request);

        return response;
    }
```

when make it from the repository, I get this response:

### Bad Request - Invalid URL

---

HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

anything I could be missing?

thx

Comment: Have you debugged what _configuration.GetValue<string>("EndPoint:EnvioPedidos") returns in the failing request?

Comment: Yes I did, it gives me correct url the same way it does when I request it from the controller

Comment: I don’t think there’s enough information to debug this. I would use a tool like Fiddler to look at the HTTP request that works and the one that fails, so I could see what is different between the two.

Comment: @PedroLeal There IS some difference in the HTTP request. If it the request was exactly the same you would not have different behavior. As already suggested, please sniff the two requests with fiddler and post the outcome here.

Comment: It's like Fiddler can't even capture the request that goes 400, like it's not even being made. The one returning 200 I can find, the wrong one tho

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got around the issue by switching to the HttpClient instead of RestSharp, now it works pretty fine. So if you're stuck here as I were you'd try it.